# What is role of JWT in authentication process?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, authorization, asp.net-identity

I'm learning purpose of JWT tokens in ASP.NET Core, but I don't understand one thing. Why does every blog calling JWT authentication? If we pass a token to an authenticated (logged-in) user. I mean why JWT is not authorization but authentication? I mean i cant understand authentication part of JWT, can't understand which point I'm skipping in this topic.

[image: Screenshot from google]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a typical implementation, the JWT token that you create for a signed in user will be sent with every subsequent request. The purpose is that you want to make sure that the party that sends the request is actually who they are claiming to be - ie. you want to authenticate requests.

Strictly speaking, without this, you could not do authorization, or well, you could, but it wouldn't make much sense if you just beleived who the caller was instead of checking (authenticating).

**Edit:**

The jwt token will always have a "sub" field, a subject, usually a user identifier, and an expiry, even if there are no further claims. The token is also signed(*) that can and must be verified. So if somebody can present a token with their identifier, signed by your server, with a timetstamp not very long ago, then you can be sure that they recently authenticated, eg. provided their password. In all subsequent requests you don't need to get their password, you only check the token. You *know* they are who they say to be, because they have a valid token, your server signed their email address, so they are logged in.

An attacker cannot forge such a token, because while they can replace or forge their user identifier (the sub field), the signature on the token will not be valid. Only your server can make a signature that can then be verified (by your server in this case).

So in other words, there is the initial user authentication, when they provide their username and password, but HTTP is basically stateless, the next HTTP query has nothing to do with the first one. You explicitly have to make this connection, ie. create a user session, you have to securely "remember" that when a new request comes in from a user, it's the same user that already provided their password. So when they do provide their password, you make a JWT for them with their email address and a timestamp, sign it, and next time they only send that, and you know it's them, because there's you signatuare on the token.

The reason you don't want them to send their password all the time is that sending passwords around in every request would present a somewhat higher risk, but much more importantly, then the client app (the browser in a webapp) would have to remember a user's password, which is not good, it's by far more secure to erase that from the browser's memory. So you create them a JWT instead.

Also note that in such a usecase, a JWT is unnecessary, maybe that's where your confusion comes from. You could just send the user a plain old random session token, which you also store on the server, and store all state in the server-side session. This is all fine, and actually more secure than a JWT. JWTs should be used for example when the authentication token needs to be sent to different origins (domains), or when secure claims should be shared with another party. Using JWTs for primary authentication with a simple web app with one origin is unnecessary (very fancy today, but not correct).

(*Note that for such a usecase, the signature is usually a message authentication code, a MAC, but I did not want to confuse you further with this word, as message authentication is *another* authentication. You can just think of this as a signature for now, though signature in cryptography is something different, and even more confusingly, JWTs can use actual signatures too.)

Comment: Thanks for explanation but again i cant fully understand purpose of the token which not contains claims in his payload, i mean if we will not use claims in token which we generated for user, then what is the role of jwt token in authentication? what we will verify with token? my eng is very bad, i wish u will understand me correctly.

Comment: I edited the answer, and don't worry, your english is good enough. :)